# Meta-tags for individual URL's

Tags: image, html, header, meta-tags, social

I am trying to create promotional pages for our magento site to run marketing campaigns from. It is very important for us to be able to share these pages on social, which means editing the open-graphs for each page so the correct image appears etc.

Is there any way for me to access the header HTML for individual pages so I can input my own meta-tags?

So far I can only add text for title and description in the back end, but images for individual pages (other than product pages) aren't proving to easy, unless I'm missing something?

Comment: Which magento version are you  using? and you want to set meta tag for product page or cms page?

Comment: Version 1.7.0.2, I want to set meta tags for a category page. I have created a category called promotions for which I will add a sub-category for each marketing campaign.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add Meta tag for category page from admin panel Just Follow image to add meta Keywords and Description [image]

Or Go to app/design/frontend/yourpackage/yourtheme/template/page/html/head.phtml

and put below code

```
<?php if(Mage::registry('current_category')):?>
<meta property="og:image" ><!--Your meta tag for category-->

<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: Thanks @murtuza, but how do I change the <meta property="og:image" - ??
Currently the image that facebook etc pulls through is just our logo and it's also the wrong size, I have an image in mind but don't know where to put it...

Comment: please check my updated answer

Comment: Have you do the changes or need some help for this Yet?